# how to use $http in a service or factory with ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, api, http, service, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the basic tabs template in ionic. Just wanted to use the $http inside a service and collect data from an API end point. It works when $http is used within a controller but it is not inside a service. This is the basic tabs template in ionic framework. I'm trying to build something on top of that just by changing the data source to my api endpoint.

```
   //Service body starts

      .service('Datas', function($http) {
     $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/api_url').then(function(response){
           var datas = response.data.items; 

  return {
    all: function() {
      return datas;
    },

    get: function(dataId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (datas[i].id === parseInt(dataId)) {
          return data[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
           });
  //Service body ends


   //controller starts here
.controller('Cntrl', function($scope, Datas) {

  $scope.data = Datas.all();

})
  //controller ends here


  //template starts
   <div ng-repeat="data in datas">
   {{data.title}}       

    </div>

  //template ends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `datas` variable declaration should be in the service construction. Not enclosed in the success handler function.

```
app.service('Datas', function($http) {
    //Declare datas here
    var datas = [];

    $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        //NOT here
        //var datas = response.data.items;
        //Also use angular.copy
        angular.copy(response.data.items, datas);
    }); 

    return {
        all: function() {
            return datas;
        },
        get: function(dataId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
                if (datas[i].id === parseInt(dataId)) {
                    return datas[i];
                };
            };
            return null;
        }
    };
});
```

Also, since the controller fetches the `datas` object reference before the XHR completes, use `angular.copy`. Avoid using an assignment statement which would replace the original object reference with a new object reference.

---

### Attaching `$promise` property

It might be wise to attach the httpPromise as a property to the `datas` object.

```
app.service('Datas', function($http) {
    //Declare datas here
    var datas = [];

    datas.$promise = $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        //NOT here
        //var datas = response.data.items;
        //Also use angular.copy
        angular.copy(response.data.items, datas);
        //return data for chaining
        return datas;
    });
```

The `$promise` property can come in handy when trying to avoid race conditions such as the controller using `Datas.get` before the XHR completes.

Comment: Hi, Tried both ways but didn't work. Not showing anything. The sample code from ionic has a dummy data like this. 



**var datas = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Peter',
    lastText: 'Klassen ',
    face: 'img/ben.png'
  }, {
    id: 1,
     name: 'Eric',
    lastText: 'Robert',
    face: 'img/max.png'
  }, {
    id: 2,
     name: 'John',
    lastText: 'Manuel',
    face: 'img/adam.jpg'
  }, {
    id: 3,
     name: 'Sam',
    lastText: 'McMannis',
    face: 'img/perry.png'
  }]; **


 I'm trying to bring up the API data instead of this dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors, the return object should be on the service scope.

```
.service('Datas', function($http) {
    var datas = null;
    $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/api_url')
        .then(function(response) {
            datas = response.data.items;
        });
    return {
        all: function() {
            return datas;
        },

        get: function(dataId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (datas[i].id === parseInt(dataId)) {
                    return data[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi, Tried the way you suggested but didn't work. Not showing anything. The sample code from ionic has a dummy data like this. 



**var datas = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Peter',
    lastText: 'Klassen ',
    face: 'img/ben.png'
  }, {
    id: 1,
     name: 'Eric',
    lastText: 'Robert',
    face: 'img/max.png'
  }, {
    id: 2,
     name: 'John',
    lastText: 'Manuel',
    face: 'img/adam.jpg'
  }, {
    id: 3,
     name: 'Sam',
    lastText: 'McMannis',
    face: 'img/perry.png'
  }]; **


 I'm trying to bring up the API data instead of this dummy data.